# Add background image when the list item will add a class when active

Tags: html, css

I have my markup something like this

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="description_tab active">
    <a href="#tab-description">Description</a>
  </li>

  <li class="reviews_tab">
    <a href="#tab-reviews">Reviews (0)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now here you can see in markup there is

```
<li class="description_tab active">
```

Here `description_tab` has a background image. but when description_tab has been activated one class active has been added and the background image for `desciption_tab` will be change. So can someone tell me how to solve this issue?

** UPDATE **

Remember that reviews_tab will also add class active wen that one will be clicked.

Comment: `.active { background: something else }` does not work?

Comment: `.background_tab.active { ... ` Would avoid unexpected effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
.description_tab { background-color:blue }
```

If you want a specifc colour on the `.description-tab` then do

```
.description_tab.active { background-color:red; }
```

And

```
.reviews_tab.active { background-color:yellow; }
```

Otherwise if you want to style `all` active backgrounds:

```
.active { background-color:red; }
```

I've used `background-color` in this example, but you can change that to `background:url... etc` if you want to use an image instead.